# How do I store byte arrays inside an object in Couchbase?

Tags: arrays, json, base64, couchbase

I want to store byte arrays (less than 1 MB) as a field value. I know about  `ByteArrayDocument` and  storing binary data as an independent non-JSON object.

To store a *field* as a byte array, do I just use `com.couchbase.client.core.utils.Base64` to build a string value?

Or is some other approach recommended?

Comment: That makes sense to me. Did you run into any issues doing this?

Comment: Just that I don't want the byte array to be indexed. Also I'm a little concerned about the 30% overhead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store it as an attribute in your JSon document, base64 would be the right approach.

However, unless your document contains only metadata about the file itself, I don't recommend using this strategy. Documents are automatically cached, and if your document is big, the cache memory will be filled quite easily.

Comment: Strings can be big too; there is nothing essential about a byte-array that makes it bigger. Also, an object can logically have properties that are byte-arrays; to store these as separate documents would seem to threaten data-integrity and require an additional query.

Comment: Yes, but a query by the key uses internally the key-value store,  it is a "cheap" extra get. So you could store in your main document only the id of the binary one. Although It all comes down to your access patterns, it might make sense in a few scenarios.